# Scrapy + Python + Xpath : datapoint couldn't be scraped always

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to scrape the address from this page:

http://calendar.youtoocanrun.com/events/chennai-1/kanchipuram-half-marathon-2018-3rd-edition/

[image]

When I am writing this xpath:

```
response.xpath('//span[@itemprop]/text()').extract()
```

I am getting desired result,i.e., a list containing the address elements:

```
[u'Chennai', u'Chennai', u'Tamil Nadu', u'India']
```

But when I am writing this xpath:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="geodir_more_info post_address"]//span[@itemprop]/text()').extract()
```

I am getting an empty list.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are two spaces between the `div` classes (`geodir_more_info` and `post_address`).

Input:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="geodir_more_info  post_address"]/span[@itemprop]/text()').extract()
```

Output:

```
[u'Chennai', u'Chennai', u'Tamil Nadu', u'India']
```